# PHP $_Session array within array index number

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables

I'm using a session array to store ingredient information. Each added ingredient has it's own array... as such

```
$_SESSION['ingredients'][] = array($_POST['ingredient'],$_POST['qty']);
```

Printing the array gives the following..

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 ) )
```

When pulling out the values of the array I am using the following...

```
$rows=$_SESSION['ingredients'];

if($rows){
foreach($rows as $row){

$sql = 'SELECT ingredient_name FROM ' . INGREDIENTS_TABLE . ' WHERE ingredient_id = '.$row[0];
$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
$ingredient = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
    $template->assign_block_vars('ingr_list', array(
    'INGREDIENT'    => $ingredient['ingredient_name'],
    'QTY'       => $row[1],
    'IDENTITY' => ****$id****, <-----HERE
    ));

}
```

What I'm looking for is the $id to equal the key value of that particular $row. Do I need to individually search the array each time I want to find it's ID (ie within the loop) or is there an easier solution?

Thanks

Comment: You are not being clear what you are trying to actually achieve, as per my question on your other question. how are you adding them and removing them. Your approach is likely to be wrong and we may all be trying to solve a problem that need not exist. If you take the time to write a question without using any lingo saying what you have, what you are trying to do and show us the code that interacts with this as well then you will get better answers rather than us just guessing what the actual problem is that you think this will solve.

Comment: Just in case I was not clear before, what in simple terms is the problem you are trying to solve. eg a user removes bananas from a recipe but which bananas do I remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
foreach($rows as $id => $row){
```

Comment: No, the keys in that array are not ids.

Comment: @Jon Oh, I must have misunderstood. Is that not what was meant by `What I'm looking for is the $id to equal the key value of that particular $row`?

Comment: The question is badly worded, but the code doesn't lie. `$_SESSION['ingredients'][]` => incrementing integer keys, not ids.

Comment: It's difficult to word questions properly when you don't know the lingo though. You have to understand that I'm a completely self taught beginner. I read code and I try to learn from it, when I get stuck I ask a question. I can only apologise for not knowing all the correct terminology, but I dare say if I did... I wouldn't require help with something that's clearly quite simple.

Comment: @Scott: I understand that, you don't need to explain yourself or apologize to anyone. What you can do is a) be up-front about this so that people are prepared to examine the question a bit more fuzzily and b) strive to improve. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need just

```
'IDENTITY' => $row[0],
```

Comment: I did try that, unfortunately that's the ID number of the ingredient rather than the key number of the array. If I have the same ingredient in twice, the same ID would be shown and it would make removing individual ingredients difficult.